# Extracting by key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given the following data, I'd like to extract 2 values for each field, the name of the field and the selected value. Maybe using `Map` ?

```js
"form_details": {
    "age": {
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "18 yrs",
          "value": "18"
        },
        {
          "label": "21 yrs",
          "selected": true,
          "value": "21"
        }
      ]
    },
    "sex": {
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "male",
          "value": "m"
        },
        {
          "label": "female",
          "selected": true,
          "value": "f"
        }
      ]
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can iterate over the keys of your input object with `Object.keys` and map them out to selected values with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const form_details={"age":{"options":[{"label":"18 yrs","value":"18"},{"label":"21 yrs","selected":!0,"value":"21"}]},"sex":{"options":[{"label":"male","value":"m"},{"label":"female","selected":!0,"value":"f"}]}}

 const result = Object.keys(form_details).map(field => {
    return {
        field,
        selected: form_details[field].options.find(o => o.selected).value
    }
 })

 console.log(result);
```